# Oracle to MySql Procedure Conversion

Tags: mysql

Just trying to convert oracle sql code to msq

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DecodeStatus(OUT oStatus VARCHAR(500), IN pStatus varchar(500))
BEGIN 
if (pStatus == 'Y') {
oStatus = 'Yes';}
elseif (pStatus == 'N'){
oStatus = 'No';}
else {oStatus = 'unknown';}
END;
```

Comment: neither of them uses `{`

Answer (score 0):

```
drop procedure if exists p;

delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE p(OUT oStatus varCHAR(500), IN pStatus varchar(500))
BEGIN 
if pStatus = 'Y' then   set oStatus = 'Yes';
elseif pStatus = 'N' then   set oStatus = 'No';
else    set oStatus = 'unknown';
end if;
END $$

delimiter ;
```